# Creating a Terrain from a Multipoint file if the "New Terrain Wizard" is missing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, terrain, las, multipoint

I created a multipoint file using the tool `LAS to Multipoint` in ArcMap. After it was done processing, I went to my geodatabase, right-clicked and attempted to create a terrain. However, the wizard that's supposed to be under "New"->"Terrain..." is not allowing me to click it.

Any ideas why it won't allow me to do make a terrain?

Comment: Do you have the 3D analyst extension? If not you can't create terrain dataset or TIN.

Comment: I do, yeah. That's why I'm confused. It works for everything else

Comment: Did you turn on the extension in Customize -> Extensions in both ArcMap and ArcCatalog?

Comment: Wow, did not know it had to be turned on in both programs. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jakub I think it may be worth writing that up as a short answer

Comment: MissingTerrain, If the answer solved your question, [you could accept it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Tks.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the extension in Customize -> Extensions in both ArcMap and ArcCatalog? Even tough you may have a licensed extension, you still need to turn them on in each application.